# Angular guard function

Tags: javascript, angular

For my application I'm trying to implement a function that shows specific options if the user is the owner of the posts on the page. The options include stuff like edit, create new etc.

Below you can see my current functions and ofcourse it works fine! However, I'd like to implement this as some form of guard but I'm not that familiar with Angular and dont see how an Angular guard can give a return value.

```
        if (this.posts.user.id === this.authService.user.id) {
          this.userOwnsPosts = true;
      }
```

Question is, how can I do this the Angular way? Doesn't have to be guards if that isnt the Angular way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, a "Guard" is an implementation of a "Route Guard", for example, the [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) interface, and is meant to work with the Router.

For showing/hiding portions of the UI, you would typically use the [NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) directive in your template, for example, once you have the function that you mentioned in your question, you could do something like:

```
<div *ngIf="userOwnsPosts">
 ...some options go here
</div>
```

If these options are "routerLinks", you might also use a route guard, but if you only use the route guard, without the ngIf, the option will still display, but won't do anything when clicked.

Answer (score -1):

Start with `this.userOwnsPosts = this.posts.user.id === this.authService.user.id;`.

In HTML template use `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="userOwnsPost">
  <button>Edit</button>
  <button>Delete</button>
  ....
</div>
```